# Ошибка выполнения скрипта на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется несколько страниц, на которых одно и то же меню, элементы меню подсвечиваются, если href ссылки элемента меню совпадает с URL страницы. Отличает их ровно одно: одна из них общая, поэтому на ней в меню нет подсвеченных элементов(то есть нет совпадений href и URL ) , а на других есть. Под меню есть ползунок, который передвигается на hover выбранного элемента меню. Собственно код такой:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var item = document.getElementsByClassName('cur-item')[0];
   $('.gallery-navigation-container ul li').on('mouseenter',
     function(evt) {
       item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (this.offsetLeft + 0) + 'px)';
     });
   var curr = document.getElementsByClassName('active-el')[0];
   $('.gallery-navigation-container ul li').on('mouseleave',
     function(evt) {
       item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (curr.offsetLeft + 0) + 'px)';
     });
   $(window).load(function() {
     item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (curr.offsetLeft + 0) + 'px)';
   });

 });
```

Cur-item - ползунок, active -el - класс элемента меню, чья ссылка совпала с url. 
ПРОБЛЕМА: на странице общей(где нет активных элементов) в косоли ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined в строках

```js
item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (curr.offsetLeft + 0) + 'px)';

item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (curr.offsetLeft + 0) + 'px)';
```

Вопрос - где я ошибся и как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var curr = document.getElementsByClassName('active-el')[0];
> ```

Нет такого элемента на момент выполнения скрипта. Перенеси это внутрь.

Comment: Все равно ошибка, может условие какое прописать?

Comment: А главное, это при первой загрузке, если перезагрузить эту страницу, то работает